# Insert into PostgreSql table with identity column not insert the row in the end of table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSql with identity column:

```
CREATE TABLE public.seller
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    ...
)
```

I want to insert a new row into seller table with id value that greater by 1 from the last row. for example: if the id of the last row is 100 so the new row will be with value 101. but when I call to 'insert statment' the row that inserted is  a row with id 1 i.e. the row was inserted to the begining of table (until now, the first id was 274).

The table is full with multi rows, but all the rows, I inserted with spesific id, just now I want to use with the default id.

Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: There is no such thing as "the end of the table" or "the beginning of the table". Rows in a relational database have no implied sort order - it's an unordered set. If you need a specific sort order in your result, you have to use `order by` in your SELECT statement.

Comment: I ment  "the end of the table" that I want the id will be the last one, like in the exaple.

Comment: Looks like you have to update the sequence first, using SELECT setval('name_of_your_sequence', 1000); --  1000 is just an example, just like the name of the sequence